# flutter nested ExpansionPanelList

Tags: flutter, dart

How can I make a nested (1, 3, 5, etc mixed) ExpansionPanelList on the page with flutter?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tmi9a.png)

I have attached a screenshot as an example.

Thank you, good luck

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I've created a StateFulWidget named `_Panel` as below which takes in `List<_Panel>? subPanelList` as argument and am iterating through it in (a kind of) recursive way..

```
class _Panel extends StatefulWidget {
  final String? panelName;
  final List<_Panel>? subPanelList;
  final _IsPanelExpanded isPanelOpen = _IsPanelExpanded();

  _Panel({
    Key? key,
    required this.panelName,
    required this.subPanelList,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<_Panel> createState() => _PanelWidget();
}

class _PanelWidget extends State<_Panel> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        border: Border.all(),
        color: Colors.blue,
      ),
      child: Column(
        children: [
          GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {
              setState(() => widget.isPanelOpen.isExpanded = !widget.isPanelOpen.isExpanded);
            },
            child: Row(
              children: [
                const SizedBox(
                  width: 15,
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: Text("${widget.panelName}"),
                ),
                const SizedBox(
                  width: 15,
                ),
                if ((widget.subPanelList ?? []).isNotEmpty)
                  Icon(widget.isPanelOpen.isExpanded ? Icons.arrow_drop_up_outlined : Icons.arrow_drop_down_outlined),
                if ((widget.subPanelList ?? []).isNotEmpty)
                  const SizedBox(
                    width: 15,
                  ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          if (widget.isPanelOpen.isExpanded)
            for (_Panel eachSubPanel in widget.subPanelList ?? [])
              Row(
                children: [
                  const SizedBox(
                    width: 15,
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    child: eachSubPanel,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class _IsPanelExpanded {
  bool isExpanded = false;
}
```

Now in the actual screen, I've declared a `List<_Panel> panels` like below,

```
List<_Panel> panels = [
  _Panel(
    panelName: "Panel",
    subPanelList: [
      _Panel(
        panelName: "Sub Panel",
        subPanelList: null,
      ),
      _Panel(
        panelName: "Sub Panel 2",
        subPanelList: null,
      ),
    ],
  ),
  _Panel(
    panelName: "Panel 2",
    subPanelList: [
      _Panel(
        panelName: "Sub Panel",
        subPanelList: [
          _Panel(
            panelName: "Sub Panel 1-1",
            subPanelList: null,
          ),
          _Panel(
            panelName: "Sub Panel 1-2",
            subPanelList: null,
          ),
          _Panel(
            panelName: "Sub Panel 1-3",
            subPanelList: null,
          ),
        ],
      ),
      _Panel(
        panelName: "Sub Panel 2",
        subPanelList: [
          _Panel(
            panelName: "Sub Panel 2-1",
            subPanelList: null,
          ),
        ],
      ),
      _Panel(
        panelName: "Panel 3",
        subPanelList: null,
      ),
    ],
  ),
];
```

Refer to the complete code here,

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class PanelListDemo extends StatefulWidget {
  const PanelListDemo({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<PanelListDemo> createState() => _PanelListDemoState();
}

class _PanelListDemoState extends State<PanelListDemo> {
  List<_Panel> panels = [
    _Panel(
      panelName: "Panel",
      subPanelList: [
        _Panel(
          panelName: "Sub Panel",
          subPanelList: null,
        ),
        _Panel(
          panelName: "Sub Panel 2",
          subPanelList: null,
        ),
      ],
    ),
    _Panel(
      panelName: "Panel 2",
      subPanelList: [
        _Panel(
          panelName: "Sub Panel",
          subPanelList: [
            _Panel(
              panelName: "Sub Panel 1-1",
              subPanelList: null,
            ),
            _Panel(
              panelName: "Sub Panel 1-2",
              subPanelList: null,
            ),
            _Panel(
              panelName: "Sub Panel 1-3",
              subPanelList: null,
            ),
          ],
        ),
        _Panel(
          panelName: "Sub Panel 2",
          subPanelList: [
            _Panel(
              panelName: "Sub Panel 2-1",
              subPanelList: null,
            ),
          ],
        ),
        _Panel(
          panelName: "Panel 3",
          subPanelList: null,
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text("Panel List Demo"),
      ),
      body: ListView(
        children: panels.map((e) => eachPanelWidget(e)).toList(),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget eachPanelWidget(_Panel e) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Container(
          margin: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
          child: e,
        ),
        Container(
          color: Colors.black,
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          height: 100,
          child: const Text(
            "Container",
            style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}

class _Panel extends StatefulWidget {
  final String? panelName;
  final List<_Panel>? subPanelList;
  final _IsPanelExpanded isPanelOpen = _IsPanelExpanded();

  _Panel({
    Key? key,
    required this.panelName,
    required this.subPanelList,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<_Panel> createState() => _PanelWidget();
}

class _PanelWidget extends State<_Panel> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        border: Border.all(),
        color: Colors.blue,
      ),
      child: Column(
        children: [
          GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {
              setState(() => widget.isPanelOpen.isExpanded = !widget.isPanelOpen.isExpanded);
            },
            child: Row(
              children: [
                const SizedBox(
                  width: 15,
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: Text("${widget.panelName}"),
                ),
                const SizedBox(
                  width: 15,
                ),
                if ((widget.subPanelList ?? []).isNotEmpty)
                  Icon(widget.isPanelOpen.isExpanded ? Icons.arrow_drop_up_outlined : Icons.arrow_drop_down_outlined),
                if ((widget.subPanelList ?? []).isNotEmpty)
                  const SizedBox(
                    width: 15,
                  ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          if (widget.isPanelOpen.isExpanded)
            for (_Panel eachSubPanel in widget.subPanelList ?? [])
              Row(
                children: [
                  const SizedBox(
                    width: 15,
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    child: eachSubPanel,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class _IsPanelExpanded {
  bool isExpanded = false;
}
```

[[image: Here is my output screenshot1]

This should pretty much suffice..